# iOS keychain implementation when using JSON to validate login

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, keychain

I've been looking through `iOS keychain` documentation all night trying to figure out how to implement it into my current code. Because I'm using parsed `JSON` passing back and forth between the app and my server, I'm using key's and `objectForKey`.

Literally all of the documentation on `keychain` is from 2011 or earlier. Is it already obsolete? Also, in all of the "`KeyChainWrapper`"s and "`SSKeychain`"s are leaving me just as stumped. Any suggestions on what to do with my code is a great help. SPECIFICALLY in relation to the `objectForKey` issue playing well with `keychain`.

**My ViewController.m file**

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    NSInteger success = 0;
    @try {

        if([[self.usernameText text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.passwordText text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.usernameText text],[self.passwordText text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/auth.php"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

            if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error:&error];

                success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];

                }

                else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }

            } else {
                //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }

}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertView.tag = tag;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to save accountName and password in keychain and retrieve that password with accountName ? Forget KeyChainWrapper, it make me confused too.

Comment: It's not obsolete. As half of the internet found to their detriment, security is difficult and making changes for changes sake is not a good idea.

Comment: @KudoCC I simply want to save both the username and password separately (if that is the norm), and be able to utilize them for auto signin after app has closed, as well as, utilize the info as needed throughout the users session (send username to database and return account info to fill app feed).

Comment: @gnasher729 I asked if it was already obsolete bc the only code and documentation I see all includes ARC stuff...thought that was handled by Xcode after 2011?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for an ARC version of the keychain wrapper. Just copy and paste the h/m files into your project. https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641

```
//create a pointer to a KeychainItemWrapper
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"loginCredentials" accessGroup:nil];

// set the credentials (email and password are NSStrings in this example)
[keychainItem setObject:email forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
[keychainItem setObject:password forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

// access an object after it has been set
NSString *email = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

// resets the contents of "loginCredentials"
[keychainItem resetKeychainItem];
```

Comment: because it's an ARC version, don't I have to make some changes to my code elsewhere? I've yet to need to utilize something like this in any of my projects. Plan to try it out in a few.

Comment: unfortunately, I just don't know where to add this code among all of my if statements. No matter where I put it, I get an exception "Couldn't add the Keychain item." If you could be so kind as to actually show me where to throw this code. Thanks.

Comment: Depends how your app is structured. In my app for example, I get the login credentials from a user and save them to the keychain using the first 3 lines above. I then send off my login request to the server. If the login comes back invalid, I reset the keychainItem and require the user to enter new credentials. If the login was a success, the app moves the user pass my login view controller and the login credentials are already saved in the keychain.

Comment: Other than just calling the object out of the keychain, how can I check to see if this was successful?

Comment: The keychain will just be used to store the credentials. You have to verify with your server that the username/password were correct.

Comment: I think that this is my issue. I'm updating my current login system to verify the user/pass. So basically everything is already there. I was hoping to simply modify my current code with the addition of the keychain. It sounds like what you're saying is that it should be setup in such a way that if the login itself is successful, than I can count on the fact that it was successfully saved to the keychain?

Comment: Exactly. I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but that is how I did it. My login view controller sends the user inputted credentials to another class. The middle class puts the credentials in the keychain and sends the appropriate data to a third class of mine which actually sends the HTTP request. The middle class then receives what the server sends back. If it is a success, it tells the view controller everything was okay. If it was a failure, it erases the keychain contents and tells the view controller it was a failure.